# What is the database name in the Room.databaseBuilder?

Tags: android-room

[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) is the official docs for Room Database. It contains the following code

```
val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
            applicationContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java, "database-name"
        ).build()
```

I was wondering what the `"database-name"` in the database builder does. What practical and tangible effects does it have?

Comment: `Room` is a Jetpack's wrapper on `Sqlite` DB. Sqlite holds data in single database file. So using "database-name" in Room's builder you'll get "database-name.db" file on filesystem. In theory one app could deal with several SQLite databases. To switch between them you use different database names. If you have single database in your app its name isn't so crucial.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. If you want to make your comment an answer, i can mark it as resolved :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Room` is a Jetpack's wrapper on `Sqlite` DB. Sqlite holds data in single database file. So using "database-name" in Room's builder you'll get "database-name.db" file on filesystem.

In theory one app could deal with several SQLite databases. To switch between them you use different database names. If you have single database in your app its name isn't so crucial

Comment: What if I want to get instance of same databse in different classes? should all of them have same database name? that seems like breaking DRY principle